# How to do two different Foreach loops without having to duplicate code

Tags: perl, foreach, code-duplication

I have a hash of arrays and a normal array, depending on the circumstances (ie what options the user chooses when the program is running) only one of these will be defined.

**Example code to demonstrate problem:**

```
my %hashofarrays;
my @array;

#...
#Some code between here where either %hashofarrays or @array gets defined
#...

if (defined @array) {

    foreach my $var1 (@array) {
        print "var1 is: $var1\n";
        call_subroutine($var1);
        print "Something else is printed";
        call_anothersubroutine($var1);
        call_differentsubroutine($var1);
    }

} 

if (defined %hashofarrays) {

    foreach my $key (keys %hashofarrays) {
        print "the key is: $key\n";
        foreach my $var1 (@{$hashofarrays{$key}}) {
            call_subroutine($var1);
            print "Something else is printed";
            call_anothersubroutine($var1);
            call_differentsubroutine($var1);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code above depending on whether the `@array` is defined or whether the `%hashofarrays` is defined it will run the corresponding `if` statement.

**The problem:**

The issue with this though is that the following lines of code are duplicated in both `if` statements:

```
    call_subroutine($var1);
    print "Something else is printed";
    call_anothersubroutine($var1);
    call_differentsubroutine($var1);
```

Obviously, if these `foreach` loops contained a lot of code, that would mean a huge amount of code would be duplicated.

Is there any way/what is the best way this duplication of code can be avoided when it comes to the `foreach` loop?

**In effect, is there a way to do something like the following:** (I am well aware this code will not work, but explains what I am trying to achieve)

```
if (defined @array) {
    foreach my $var1 (@array) {
} elsif (defined %hashofarrays) {
    foreach my $key (keys %hashofarrays) {
        print "the key is: $key\n";
        foreach my $var1 (@{$hashofarrays{$key}}) {

} #ending bracket of if statement

        call_subroutine($var1);
        print "Something else is printed";
        call_anothersubroutine($var1);
        call_differentsubroutine($var1); 

}  #ending bracket of whatever foreach loop is used
```

I may well be overlooking something obvious here but cannot see a logical way to do this?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574215/do-something-if-key-exists-in-hash1-and-not-in-hash2

Comment: Using `defined` on arrays and hashes is deprecated.

Comment: @perl-user It was [deprecated in v5.6.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `defined @array` and `defined %hashofarrays` is *wrong*. They are always defined. You want `if (@array)` and `if (keys %hashofarrays)` to test if they *contain* elements. You should have even gotten an warning `defined(@array) is deprecated`!

What you want is another subroutine.

```
sub loop_body {  # just use some better name!
  my ($var) = @_;
  call_subroutine($var);
  print "Something else is printed";
  call_anothersubroutine($var);
  call_differentsubroutine($var);
}
```

Then:

```
if (@array) {
    foreach my $var1 (@array) {
        print "var1 is: $var1\n";
        loop_body($var1);
    }
} elsif (keys %hashofarrays) {
    foreach my $key (keys %hashofarrays) {
        print "the key is: $key\n";
        foreach my $var1 (@{$hashofarrays{$key}}) {
            loop_body($var1)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use callbacks to make your solution more flexible:

```
 sub loop_with_cb {
   my $cb = shift;
   for my $var (@_) {
     if ($cb) {
       local $_ = $var; # make $_ visible to the callback
       $cb->($var);
     }
     call_subroutine($var);
     print "Something else is printed";
     call_anothersubroutine($var);
     call_differentsubroutine($var);
   }
 }
```

Then:

```
if (@array) {
    loop_with_cb(
      sub { print "var1 is: $_\n" },
      @array,
    );
} elsif (keys %hashofarrays) {
    foreach my $key (keys %hashofarrays) {
        print "the key is: $key\n";
        loop_with_cb(undef, @{ $hashofarrays{$key} });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `for (@_){ my $var = $_; }` instead of `local $_ = $var;`

Comment: @mpapec I thought about that, but I think it is important to use explicit, lexical loop variables whenever possible. An explicit `local` is also a strong way of saying “I wish to make this visible to the subs I'm calling.” Implicit behaviour should be avoided considering OP's knowledge of Perl.

Comment: I've red some time ago about manual localization of `$_`, but can't remember why it should be avoided. I'll try to find that article.

Comment: @mpapec I would be interested in such an article. But are you sure you aren't confusing it with lexical `$_`? Nowadays, `my $_` is discouraged along with the other mistakes from 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

Using another function might be helpful,

```
if (@array) {
    my_func(\@array);
} 
if (%hashofarrays) {
    foreach my $key (keys %hashofarrays) {
        print "the key is: $key\n";
        my_func($hashofarrays{$key});
    }
}

sub my_func {
    my ($arr) = @_;

    foreach my $var1 (@$arr) {
        call_subroutine($var1);
        print "Something else is printed";
        call_anothersubroutine($var1);
        call_differentsubroutine($var1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As amon said, `if (defined @array)` is wrong, but I wouldn't even bother with `if (@array)` unless you're going to have an `else`.  You can go straight to `for (@array)` and, if `@array` is empty, it will iterate zero times, essentially skipping over the loop just like the `if` would.

With that out of the way, it looks like you want to do the same thing for every element in `@array` and every key in `%hash of arrays`, right?  You don't even need a `sub` for that:

```
for (@array, map { @$_ } values %hashofarrays) {
  my $var1 = $_;
  print "var is: $var1\n";
  call_subroutine($var1);
  print "Something else is printed";
  call_anothersubroutine($var1);
  call_differentsubroutine($var1);
}
```

**Edit:** Revised code to loop over the contents of the arrays in `%hashofarrays` rather than its keys.  This still isn't an exact match for the code in the initial question, since it prints `$var1` when looping over the hoa instead of printing the hash keys, but it looks like there's a good chance that the OP's real use case doesn't use the key for anything other than indexing into the hash, in which case it's not really needed anyhow (since we can use `values %hoa` instead).

Comment: That wont work, since `$_` represents the content of a field in the array, but in the hash it's just the key, not the value. As far as I see, the value of the key from the hash is needed in the hash-specific for-loop. And since the hash is filled with array-refs, this wouldn't work even if there's some way to make `$_` the value of the hash-entry.

Comment: @Vince: Ah, good catch! I'll revise my answer to loop over `@array` and the contents of the arrays in `%hashofarrays` instead.